Unable to include Qt StateMachine in Yocto image
I am building custom board's image with yocto (poky-kirkstone) and meta-qt6(6.7.0). I would like rootfs image to have Qt StateMachine libraries. Image generated has many packages from Qt except statemachine. Am I supposed to provide any different configuration to include statemachine while compiling Qt?
I had tried looking over different branches of meta-qt6, but none talks about state machine in their PAKAGECONFIG. I am expecting some way to include state machine in Qt package.

Including qtscxml in image file worked for me.
